# Python Requests and Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests

I am using the requests library to query the Diffbot API to get contents of an article from a web page url. When I visit a request URL that I create in my browser, it returns a JSON object with the text in Unicode (right?) for example (I shortended the text somewhat):

> {"icon":"http://mexico.cnn.com/images/ico_mobile.jpg","text":"CIUDAD
>   DE MÉXICO (CNNMéxico) \u2014 Kassandra Guazo Cano tiene 32 años, pero
>   este domingo participó por primera vez en una elección.\n\"No había
>   sacado mi (credencial del) IFE (Instituto Federal Electoral) porque al
>   hacer el trámite hay mucha mofa cuando ven que tu nombre no coincide
>   con tu y otros documentos de acuerdo con su nueva identidad.\nSánchez
>   dice que los solicitantes no son discriminados, pero la experiencia de
>   Kassanda es diferente: \"hay que pagar un licenciado, dos peritos
>   (entre ellos un endocrinólogo). Además, el juez dicta sentencia para
>   el cambio de nombre y si no es favorable tienes que esperar otros
>   cuatro años para volver a demandar al registro civil\".\nAnte esta
>   situación, el Consejo para Prevenir y Eliminar la sculina, los
>   transgénero votan - México: Voto 2012 -
>   Nacional","url":"http://mexico.cnn.com/nacional/2012/07/02/con-apariencia-de-mujer-e-identidad-masculina-los-transexuales-votan","xpath":"/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/SECTION[5]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[6]"}

When I use the python request library as follows:

```
def get_article(self, params={}):
  api_endpoint = 'http://www.diffbot.com/api/article'
  params.update({
    'token': self.dev_token,
    'format': self.output_format,
  })
  req = requests.get(api_endpoint, params=params)
  return json.loads(req.content)
```

It returns this (again note that I shortened the text somewhat):

> {u'url':
>   u'http://mexico.cnn.com/nacional/2012/07/02/con-apariencia-de-mujer-e-identidad-masculina-los-transexuales-votan',
>   u'text': u'CIUDAD DE M\xc9XICO (CNNM\xe9xico) \u2014 Kassandra Guazo
>   Cano tiene 32 a\xf1os, pero este domingo particip\xf3 por primera vez
>   en una elecci\xf3n.\n"No hab\xeda sacado mi (credencial del) IFE
>   (Instituto Federal Electoral) porque al hacOyuky Mart\xednez Col\xedn,
>   tambi\xe9n transg\xe9nero, y que estaba acompa\xf1ada de sus dos hijos
>   y su mam\xe1.\nAmbas trabajan como activistas en el Centro de Apoyo a
>   las Identidades Trans, A.C., donde participan en una campa\xf1a de
>   prevenci\xf3n de enfermedades sexuales.\n"Quisi\xe9ramos que no solo
>   nos vean como trabajadoras sexuales o estilistas, sino que luchamos
>   por nuestros derechos", dice Kassandra mientras sonr\xede, sostiene su
>   credencial de elector y levanta su pulgar entintado.', u'title': u'Con
>   apariencia de mujer e identidad masculina, los transg\xe9nero votan -
>   M\xe9xico: Voto 2012 - Nacional', u'xpath':
>   u'/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/SECTION[5]/DIV[1]/ARTICLE[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[6]',
>   u'icon': u'http://mexico.cnn.com/images/ico_mobile.jpg'}

I don't quite understand Unicode. How to make sure that what I get with requests is still Unicode?

Comment: Looks like you have unicode strings in that json result.  Notice the "u'...'" notation?  You can also check the type of some of the result: `type(result['text'])`.  http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks! I see it is unicode indeed with the u'', however it says prevenci\xf3n (when using requests) instead of preferiría (in browser) for example. How can I make it that that prevenci\xf3n is preferiría?

Comment: That's just plain old string literal syntax. Python shows you `\xc9` because that's safe to print on all consoles, whereas `É` would fail on consoles that don't support Unicode properly. If your console is working, you can see they are the same. `>>> u'CIUDAD DE M\xc9XICO'==u'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO'` is True.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `req.text` instead of `req.content` to ensure that you get Unicode. This is described in:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text

Comment: is there a way to not get a unicode JSON response with Requests? It seems like the only way to print out a JSON response to terminal without the unicode is to print the JSON as a string, but then of course it's not a data structure anymore, just a string. Is there a way to deal with Request responses as "pure" JSON still as a data structure but with no Unicode?

Comment: NB: In some instances it is necessary to do `response.content.decode('utf-8')` to convert the raw bytes to UTF-8.

Answer (score 15):

Concerning the "I don't quite understand unicode", there's an [entertaining primer](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on Unicode by Joel Spolsky and the official [Python Unicode HowTo](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) which is a 10 minute read and covers everything Python specific.

The [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) say that request will always return unicode, and the example content you posted is in fact unicode (notice the `u''` string syntax? That's Python's syntax for unicode strings.), so there's no problem. Note that if you view the JSON response in a web browser, the `u''` will not be there because it's a property of how Python stores a string.

If unicode is important to your application, please don't try to cope without really knowing about unicode. You're in for a world of pain, character set issues are extremely frustrating to debug if you don't know what you're doing. Reading both articles mentioned above maybe takes half an hour.

Comment: Add to those links Ned Batchelder's excellent presentation on Pragmatic Unicode in Python: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Thanks! I see it is unicode indeed with the u'', however it says prevenci\xf3n (when using requests) instead of preferiría (in browser) for example. How can I make it that that prevenci\xf3n is preferiría?

Comment: Python uses an escape sequence like `\xf3` for every non-ASCII character when *displaying* a unicode string. Looking at the Unicode charts at http://www.unicode.org/charts/, you'll see it's an "ó", so it's all right. If you want to see the actual character, you'll need to encode the unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

Try `response.content.decode('utf-8')` if `response.text` doesn't work.

According to the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response), the main problem is that the encoding guessed by `requests` is determined based solely on the HTTP headers. If you can take advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you can set `response.encoding` before accessing `response.text`.

Credit goes to Jay Taylor for commenting on TTT's answer - I almost missed the comment and thought it deserved its own answer.