# tokenltk word_tokenize() tokenizes the same word two different ways in different functions

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, tokenize, python-unicode

I have a name of a tennis player that apparently is not parsed correctly by pandas. It is "radwa?ska". I have two functions where I tokenize using the `word_tokenize()` function. 
It tokenizes the sentence in two different ways
 in the two different functions. How do I get the second one to go the first way
`['radwa?ska']`
`['radwa','?','ska']`
Here's the code in both the functions.
first function:
`word_tokenize(keyword)` the keyword is `'martina hingis, nadia petrova, agnieszka radwa?ska'`
and in the second function is:
`word_tokenize(content[j])` where content[j] is `'agnieszka radwa?ska'`
.

Answer (score 1):

For both sentence in your original post, they should return the same output:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> text1 = 'martina hingis, nadia petrova, agnieszka radwa?ska'
>>> text2 = 'agnieszka radwa?ska'

>>> word_tokenize(text1)
['martina', 'hingis', ',', 'nadia', 'petrova', ',', 'agnieszka', 'radwa', '?', 'ska']

>>> word_tokenize(text2)
['agnieszka', 'radwa', '?', 'ska']
```

It's because the `TreebankWordTokenizer` object behind `word_tokenize` always always puts a space before and after a question mark at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L80

---

One can hack some ways to disable that regex but it will cause problems somewhere else down the road.

But I urge you to take a closer look at how you're reading/collecting your data, the fact that `radwa?ska` appears hint at some encoding problems exists upstream before tokenization. The correct reading of the file/stream would have got you `radwańska`.

See also

- [Unicode (UTF-8) reading and writing to files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf-8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)
- [Python Requests and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435331/python-requests-and-unicode)

Comment: I checked upstream and found out that, in the dataframe I have `radwańska`. When I write to csv using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv(path)` it messes up the name. Then I tried `utf-8-sig` encoding which correctly wrote to csv, but that gave `unicode-error` later when I tried to `pandas.DataFrame.read_csv(path)` . I used various combinations of `utf-8`,`utf-8-sig`,`latin1` but none worked