# Troubleshooting request JSON in Flask

Tags: json, python-2.7, flask, unicode

My Flask web service has this code:

```
@app.route('/api/my_service', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_service():
    try:
        content = request.get_json()
        print type(content)
        print 'content', content
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()
```

My client calls this:

```
input = {'my_key': 1, 'other_key': 2}
url ='http://local:5000/api/my_service'
res = requests.post(url, json=input)
if res.ok:
    print res.text
```

The output is this
    
     content {u'my_key': 1, u'other_key': 2}

It looks like my dictionary is being converted incorrectly. How can I trouble-shoot this?

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get POSTed json in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask)

Comment: Those questions don't address why the dictionary is coming up in unicode.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435633/8916412 **"The requests docs say that request will always return unicode, and the example content you posted is in fact unicode (notice the u'' string syntax? That's Python's syntax for unicode strings.), so there's no problem. Note that if you view the JSON response in a web browser, the u'' will not be there because it's a property of how Python stores a string."**

Comment: Although, by switching to Python 3, you will get rid of that.